# What is the word for acting as if you are going to give someone something, but you won't?

Tags: word-choice

Let's they there is a kid with a cookie and a dog, and the kid intentionally bring his hand with the cookie to the dog as if he is going to give it the cookie. Once the dog reacts the kid jerk it away to make fun of it. What word would be the most appropriate to use in the context. Can I say this?

> *The kid is teasing the dog with a cookie.*

Comment: There's nothing wrong with *teasing*, if that's how you want to describe the behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The kid is teasing the dog with a cookie" is exactly right.

From https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tease :

"to disturb or annoy by persistent irritating or provoking especially in a petty or mischievous way"